Newly added task to an existing dag ran for prior period. Is this expected?
I have a dag deployed and executing weekly/monthly in MWAA (AWS). I addedd new task to the existing dag and deployed. I see the new task kicked off for last week and month.
Is the expected?
 default_args = {
        'owner'           : 'airflow'
        ,'depends_on_past' : False
        ,'start_date'      : datetime(2024, 9, 1)
        ,'retries'         : 2
        ,'retry_delay'     : timedelta(minutes=60)
        ,'provide_context' : True
        ,'email'           : ['ai.com']
        ,'email_on_failure': False
        ,'email_on_retry'  : False
    }

    dag = DAG(
        dag_id                   = dag_id
        ,default_args            = default_args
        ,description             = 'To populaasets'
        ,dagrun_timeout          = timedelta(hours=48)
        ,schedule                = schedule
        ,catchup                 = False
        ,is_paused_upon_creation = True
    )


